# ONE of my sources doesn't show up right in Latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, apa7

All my sources are showing up correctly in Latex expect one. Can you help me?

The source is as follows:

```
 @article{bharadwaj2013digital,
  title={Digital business strategy: toward a next generation of insights},
  author={Bharadwaj, Anandhi and El Sawy, Omar A and Pavlou, Paul A and Venkatraman, N v},
  journal={MIS quarterly},
  pages={471--482},
  year={2013},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

It's published in APA style, and shows up as (A. Bharadwaj et al., 2013) --> The correct citation is (Bharadwaj et al., 2013) how can I fix this?

Packages are as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend = biber,
            style = apa,  
            urldate = long, 
            maxcitenames = 2,   
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Comment: Is there any other item with the Bharadwaj last name in your bibliography? If it is and also if it has some other name (not Anandhi) then `biblatex` adds the initial to make sure the authors are distinguishable in the text. Adding `uniquename=false` to the biblatex options may help.

Comment: A cite with the initials seems odd, but has the logic that Sergei explained very well. What you should check now is if this rule is mandatory of the APA style (afaik, it is) and then if you have a good reason to surpass this rule. That your supervisor or a thesis committee demand a APA style, but they could be not aware of all APA rules,  is **not** among the good reasons.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan, that is correct. I have another source with the name, but it has a different date and other authors, so I thought it would auto-correct that. 

So if I understand you correctly, adding uniquename=false might correct that?

Comment: @Fran I agree, and absolutely testing Sergei's suggestion :)

Comment: @SergeiGolovan added that in and now it looks like it's corrected, thank you so much for your help! :D